# What's the rails way of nesting routes with shared models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following models:

```
board.rb
task.rb
comment.rb
```

Board has many comments, comment belongs to board. Task has many comments, comment belong to task. Board has many tasks, task belongs to board.

What is the cleanest way of handling the routes? It currently looks like this:

```
resources :boards do
  resources :tasks do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :comments
end
```

Which produces the following snake after `rake routes`:

`board_task_comment GET    /boards/:board_id/tasks/:task_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show`

How would I go about making it shorter and cleaner? Is there a "Rails way" of doing it? (Custom routes is the only idea i can come up with)

EDIT: Added missing associations.

Comment: If board has_many comments and even Task has_many comments, go for a polymorphic association, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html go to 2.9. Thats the best practise

Answer (score 1):

Go for polymorphic association

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

Routes

```
resources :boards do
  resources :comments
end
resources :tasks do
  resources :comments
end
```

Comment: I added a missing association which was mentioned by a deleted answer before. Does your answer still apply? (I forgot to mention the board has_many tasks, task belongs_to board relation)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to share nested routes use [routing concerns](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns):

```
concern :commentable do
  resources :comments
end

resources :boards, concerns: :commentable

resources :tasks, concerns: :commentable
```

That way if you you don't repeat yourself.